# Index Specific entry located in connected database [IDOL Indexing server]

Tags: hp-idol-ondemand

I have a problem. I have a database and the entries of it, indexes at a specific time in IDOL indexing server. The problem is that a speficic entry has not been indexed for reason. Is there any way to force index it? Ideally, for a URL action call.  I know that DREREGENERATE may be what I want but I don't understand how to specify my entry ID.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually create the IDX for the entry and use DREADD action to add the entry to the IDOL content DB. Easily achievable using a python script and HTTP Post.

The following document shows the various parameters which can be used in DREADD action.

https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/idol/IDOL_12_2/Content_12.2_Documentation/Help/index.html#Index%20Actions/IndexData/_IX_DREADD.htm?Highlight=DREADD

Comment: This is what I end up doing. But due to the design of the system that I'm working on I could find (or create) the IDX/XML of my document. Finally, I found that the application produces an XML file for this purpose so I use the suggested command. Thank you very much.